# 0 kernels running but terminal says file doesn't exist

Tags: python, macos, terminal, jupyter-notebook

When I run Jupyter notebooks from terminal, terminal keeps showing that these two files DO NOT exist. But nothing is running. Even when I am running programs these lines below keep showing up intermittently. None of the code I'm running is asking for these files.

I ran a block of code a while ago that asked for these files but since then I deleted them and stopped that program but its still asking for it.

Any help would be great!

As a side note, Jupyter notebooks is running perfectly, just wondering why these notifications are popping up.

```
[I 10:58:18.078 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory:/Users/greg
[I 10:58:18.078 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 10:58:18.078 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 10:58:18.078 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 10:58:19.313 NotebookApp] /Users/greg/cv.py doesn't exist
[W 10:58:19.313 NotebookApp] /Users/greg/cv2.so doesn't exist
[W 10:58:35.274 NotebookApp] /Users/greg/cv.py doesn't exist
[W 10:58:35.275 NotebookApp] /Users/greg/cv2.so doesn't exist
```